# OpenMP: re-writing a for loop so it can be parallelised?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, loops, openmp

I'm trying to parallelise the FEM1D code that can be found [here](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/fem1d/fem1d.c). The part that's relevant is:

```
for ( i = 1; i < nu - 1; i++ )
{
 adiag[i] = adiag[i] - aleft[i] * arite[i-1];
 arite[i] = arite[i] / adiag[i];
}
```

simply adding

```
 #pragma omp parallel for
```

before the loop does not work and im not sure why. I assume that its because the other threads need to update the arrays but since i is private the threads shouldn't need to update anything required by another thread?.

i've tried making new variables making them private but im pretty sure its to do with updating the adiag and arite arrays so i tried the flush directive which specifies that all threads have the same view of memory for all shared objects, but again no dice.

```
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,ad,al,ar)
 for ( i = 1; i < nu - 1; i++ )
 {
  #pragma omp flush(adiag, arite, aleft)
  ad = adiag[i];
  al = aleft[i];
  ar = arite[i-1];
  adiag[i] = ad - al * ar;
  ar = arite[i];
  ad = adiag[i];
  arite[i] = ar / ad;
}
```

so im pretty stuck here, any advice to help me along would be much appreciated.

EDIT: by does not work i mean that the arrays adiag and arite are incorrectly filled in after the loop completed

EDIT2: ive gotten the loop to work with

```
#pragma omp parallel for ordered
for ( i = 1; i < nu - 1; i++ )
{
#pragma omp ordered
 adiag[i] = adiag[i] - aleft[i] * arite[i-1];
 arite[i] = arite[i] / adiag[i];
}
```

but I believe it kinda defeats the purpose of parallelising the loop in the first place

Comment: the computation `i` inside the loop body depends on the previous result `i-1` - this cannot be parallelised

Comment: by does not work i mean that the arrays adiag and arite are incorrectly filled in after the loop completed

Comment: Ok yep I can see how i-1 is a problem. by this cannot be parallelised do you mean completely? or is their a way to rewrite it?

Comment: Trade space for time -- make a copy of `arite` before entering the loop, read from `arite_old`, write to `arite_new`.

Comment: Why have you made your computation `ordered` ?

Comment: im not sure what you mean by read from arite_old and write to arite_new either as isn't the whole problem that i need to read a new state of arite potentially before its been updated. eg: say it loops 100 times, thread 2 will start with i = 25 but it will need i = 24 to have been completed first so that arite[i-1] or arite[24] is the correct updated figure.. sorta explains my thinking behind using ordered.

Comment: As @BeyelerStudios has briefly said: there are some algorithms that cannot be parallelized. Any algorithm where each iteration depends on the previous iteration is an inherently serial algorithm. You must either stick with a serial algorithm or rewrite the algorithm in a way such that there is no inter-iteration dependence. Yes, ordered will work, but also yes as you've mentioned it defeats the purpose of parallelizing.

Comment: Ok ill leave that bit alone until i understand the code enough to possibly re-write it without the inter-iteration dependence. thanks for all your help

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll, the prefix sum/cumulative sum depends on the previous element but it can be parallelized in two passes.

Answer (score 1):

I Don't think you can convert this loop. You have a cyclical data dependency. Usually when you have a loop that can be converted, you swap the commands order and you solve your loop problem like so:

```
for ( i = 1; i < nu - 1; i++ )
{
   arite[i-1] = arite[i-1] / adiag[i-1];
   adiag[i] = adiag[i] - aleft[i] * arite[i-1];
}
```

Although, when you do that, you steel need to use a value computed by another thread. I could be wrong though...